# Snaps don't respect mouse cursor

Tags: themes, 18.04, cursor

Some snaps installed via Ubuntu software center (18.04) don't respect system mouse cursor, even though that cursor works everywhere else, on that package it looks very weird. Snaps that has this issue for me are chromium and discord, spotify, simplenote. Using default Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I have trouble with snaps. I have much less trouble installing with apt or even building from source. Snaps are really a convenience for developers. For users they are more often a pain.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue which was solved by changing the cursor theme and restarting it. Earlier my cursor theme was the one with `vimix` theme, but changing it to `DMZ-white` worked and had the same result as `vimix` theme didn't have a different cursor design.

Possible reason for this behaviour is that the snap apps don't recognize this new theme, but am not so sure of it.