# No cursor theme on snap apps

Tags: snap, cursor-theme

Is there any progress on this one?
Here is the same question from 2018. with no response [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030972/snaps-dont-respect-mouse-cursor).
Issue is still persist.
I can not comment because of my reputation level, so I raised another question with same topic.

Comment: This is more likely a bug or snap behavior as it happens across multiple Linux distributions.

Comment: It's a bug. But it's not addressed for quite a long time. Also, there is all sorts of issues regarding default system themes integration with snaps apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are snaps and snaps. Snap applications like gimp and firefox are themed perfectly because the developers have added the correct plugs to the snap while building it. Then there are snaps like spotify and vlc which aren't themed because they don't have access to the correct plug. So while the issue is fixed on the snap side it's the developers of individual apps that have to update their apps to take advantage of theming.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. I've searched for hours to find appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what is happening, is that some, most or all snap apps doesn't recognize all cursor theme. For example, on postman snap app, cursor theme Yaru is not recognized, while DMZ white theme is recognized. Just tested on Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 beta.