# My cursor theme not working inside Firefox in 21.10

Tags: firefox, snap, cursor-theme

I have my own cursor theme which works almost everywhere else inside 21.10. But inside `Firefox`, I see that the cursor falls back to default. Is there any method to make sure that the cursor remains the same inside `Firefox` as well ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try installing the .deb version of Firefox, and `sudo snap remove firefox` to remove the snap version.

Comment: thanks. But there is no .deb file available on Mozilla site

Comment: Does this answer your question? [21.10 Firefox Missing Profiles](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369493/21-10-firefox-missing-profiles)

Comment: The .deb version is available in the Ubuntu Software store.

Comment: @N0rbert how are these questions similar ? I do not get any error at all. Everything works fine for me, except the cursor theme.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue is even more apparent in HiDPI where the mouse cursor is tiny.

Starting from Ubuntu 21.10, Firefox is installed from snap by default (as opposed to from `.deb` in previous versions of Ubuntu). [Upgrading Ubuntu from 21.04 to 21.10](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/feature-freeze-exception-seeding-the-official-firefox-snap-in-ubuntu-desktop/24210/97) will also seamlessly change the installed Firefox to use the snap version.
source: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/feature-freeze-exception-seeding-the-official-firefox-snap-in-ubuntu-desktop/24210?u=d0od

Some snap applications work well (with mouse theming and resolution scaling), while others need to be fixed by the developers to update their apps to take advantage of theming.
source: https://askubuntu.com/a/1225244/721271

At the moment, both versions of Firefox are available through *Ubuntu Software*. If you want, you can remove the snap version and install the `.deb` version, as a temporary workaround (or **continue using Firefox's snap version** which will eventually get fixed).
[image]

Alternatively, use the command line (*perhaps back-up your Firefox profile first*):

```
sudo snap remove firefox
sudo apt install firefox
```

Also, try temporarily switching to the `Yaru` cursor theme using the `GNOME Tweaks` app and see if it helps, as a possible workaround for now.

Comment: I added the .deb version from the Ubuntu store and the custom cursor theme works fine as before. Thanks.

Comment: As Firefox is now only available on snap, this fix no longer works.

Comment: Changing the cursors back to Yaru solved it for me in Ubuntu 22.04 (snappy fox). Changing them back to nordzy created the see-saw mentioned, cursor changes back to Yaru (gnat-sized) when in Firefox. Mozilla snap devs will probably fix this one day!?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, I found that there was 2 snap connections missing for Firefox package.

```
sudo snap connect firefox:icon-themes gtk-common-themes:icon-themes
sudo snap connect firefox:sound-themes gtk-common-themes:sound-themes
```

Comment: It worked perfectly for me! The question's been around for 11 months, and you answered it the day I needed it. Great coincidence, isn't it?