# Tiny cursor in Firefox snap

Tags: firefox, snap, cursor, scaling

I just migrated from Ubuntu `20.04` to `22.04`, and Firefox migrated to snap.

As a result, I have a problem where mouse cursor is tiny inside Firefox window.

[image]
[image]

I have display scale at 200%, so I guess that is part of the problem.

Is there any workaround for this? I saw many questions around the internet, but I found no clear steps to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI:: Just started to experience *same issue*, but have been using **22.04** and **Firefox (snap)** for some time. The two theme connections (suggested below) are **not** missing.

Comment: Resolved by latest (snap) update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that **icon-themes** and **sound-themes** connections are missing:

```
snap connections firefox
```

Enable connections:

```
sudo snap connect firefox:icon-themes gtk-common-themes:icon-themes
sudo snap connect firefox:sound-themes gtk-common-themes:sound-themes
```

[source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1433010/440005)

*similar questions*: [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1430107/), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1432308/), [3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1432707/)

Comment: That works, thanks!

Comment: So, you have to do this for each and every Snap app, right?

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, connections properly set by snap on update doesn't work in my case.
But after disconnecting and connecting, mouse cursor became normal.

```
$ sudo snap disconnect firefox:icon-themes
$ sudo snap connect firefox:icon-themes gtk-common-themes:icon-themes
```

Not sure how does this "manual" connection will behave on snap update, but will see.