# How can I get back the default cursor over links in Ubuntu 22.04 with Firefox snap?

Tags: firefox, snap, wayland, cursor

I upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04 and now my cursor looks **UGLY**[image] on hover over links.
How can I disable that or get back the old Firefox cursor icon? Preferably without using the apt package as explained here: [How to install Firefox as a traditional deb package (without snap) in Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22/1404401#1404401)

Comment: The only way would be with the non snap package. You can not change the contents of a snap. Perhaps Firefox support has some hidden config tip.

Comment: That is what I was hoping for, a Firefox setting to change this abomination. I checked all the settings but found nothing, but maybe I can replace a file somewhere on my system?

Comment: A system file does not change what happens in a snap. That is the whole idea snaps are a closed system.

Comment: I see, makes sense to some degree, makes user configuration also harder so not a big fan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check that **icon-themes** and **sound-themes** connections are missing:

```
snap connections firefox
```

Enable connections:

```
sudo snap connect firefox:icon-themes gtk-common-themes:icon-themes
sudo snap connect firefox:sound-themes gtk-common-themes:sound-themes
```

[source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1433010/440005)

*similar questions*: [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1430107/), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1432308/), [3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1432707/)