# Kubuntu 20.04 snap packages don't respect cursor theme

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, snap, cursor, cursor-theme

I'm using the Bibata cursor theme on Kubuntu 20.04 and whenever I move my mouse to a snap application it reverts to dmz-white. I'm assuming that it just isn't in gtk-common-themes. Is there any way at all to get my custom cursor to display in a snap application like something I can snap connect to make it work?

Comment: Yeah! It's a bug. Whenever you hover your mouse on a Snap Application, the mouse will disappear or will turn into some other theme. It's with almost all icon themes. I'd recommend changing your GTK3 theme to something supportive.

Comment: Ah, well that's frustrating then but not a huge issue. I imagine it's pretty low on the priority list to fix. Thanks for letting me know, I hope that it gets fixed soon.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225235/no-cursor-theme-on-snap-apps, a question that unfortunately has been closed. One unfortunately cannot answer here that a concern actually is caused by an issue that is considered a bug.